# Bootstrap 3 -> 4 Issues

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am trying to update some code that worked with some iteration of Bootstrap version 3. I am targeting version 4.3.1 now. I am trying to change this navbar code, but since the navbar had a big overhaul from 3->4 I am having a lot of issues.

I read through...
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/
Which goes over migrating to v4, but still cant get it to work

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-top:17px; background-color:white; opacity: 0.7;">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <%=link_to image_tag("logo.svg", size:"150x59"), store_index_path, :class => "navbar-brand", method: :get %>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><%= link_to t('.questions'), store_index_path, class: "navbar_main_links" %></li>
          <li><%= link_to t('.news'), store_index_path, class: "navbar_main_links" %></li>
          <li><%= link_to t('.contact'), store_index_path, class: "navbar_main_links" %></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Cog_font_awesome.svg/512px-Cog_font_awesome.svg.png" alt="gear"> </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <% if session[:user_id] %>
                <li><%= link_to "Orders", orders_path, class: "navbar_main_links" %></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Products", products_path, class: "navbar_main_links" %></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path, class: "navbar_main_links" %></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method: :delete, class: "navbar_main_links" %></li>
              <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to "Login", login_path, class: "navbar_main_links" %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/61/61027.png" alt="gear" id="navbar_image_locale"> </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <% LANGUAGES.each_with_index do |language, index|%>
                <li><a href=""><%= link_to language[0].to_s, store_index_url(locale: language[1]), class: "navbar_main_links" %></a></li>
                <% if index != LANGUAGES.size-1 %>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="mx-2 my-auto d-inline w-100">
          <%= form_tag(store_index_path, method: :get) do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, '', class: 'form-control border border-right-0' %>
            <%= image_submit_tag "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-web-browser/100/search-512.png", id: "navbar_search_image_submit" %>
          <% end %>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I changed around some things but still when displaying this it will pretty much just show the image file from the ERB code and a checkbox that, once clicked, will use the collapse dropdown button.

Im pretty sure I am just using a depreciated class or something, but I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Faild migration.

As you have gussed, most of the clases you are using are not available in version 4.  I think you should copy the template from bootstrap and use it. Or if you are using an editor like Intellij, check if the class name you are using exists in version 4.

---

This is a similar layout as of yours.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="" width="30" height="30" alt="">
  </a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <li class="dropdown-item">Action</li>
          <li class="dropdown-item" >Another action</li>
          <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item">Something else here</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <li class="dropdown-item">Action</li>
          <li class="dropdown-item" >Another action</li>
          <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item">Something else here</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYZjNv

Comment: Thanks, I just decided to do what you recommended and use a bootstrap 4 compliant navbar template and add my functionality to it. Works fine now.